# How can I add services inside my own service forwarding the IOptions?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am building my own package in order to abstract the user from some stuffs.

My original `Startup.cs` looked like

```cs
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                // Store the session to cookies
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

                // OpenId authentication
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
         .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         .AddOpenIdConnect(o =>
            {
                // URL of the Keycloak server
                o.Authority = Configuration["Jwt:Authority"];

                // Client configured in the Keycloak
                o.ClientId = Configuration["Jwt:ClientId"];

                ...
             }
```

I want to extract those Add* methods in my own package like this:

```cs
    public static class MyExtension 
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddMyAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add ASP.NET Core Options libraries - needed so we can use IOptions<SVOSOptions>
            services.AddOptions();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                // Store the session to cookies
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

                // OpenId authentication
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddOpenIdConnect(o =>
            {
                // URL of the Keycloak server
                o.Authority = * MyOptions.Authority *;

                // Client configured in the Keycloak
                o.ClientId = * MyOptions.ClientId *

                ...

            });


            return services;
        }

        public static IServiceCollection AddMyAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, Action<MyOptions> configure)
        {
            if (services == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
            }

            if (configure != null)
            {
                services.Configure(configure);
            }

            return services.AddMyAuthentication();
        }
    }
```

Of course I want to replace all the Configuration[] calls within my class with some options which I want to send from my new `Startup.cs` like this:

```cs
services.AddMyAuthentication(options => {
       options.Authority = Configuration["Jwt:Authority"];
       options.ClientId = Configuration["Jwt:ClientId"];
})
```

I'm also doing this because I want to hardcode that the user doesn't need to know. I hope that this is the right way to do something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just using the resulting settings during the service registration and you don't have a need to register those options into the service provider for later injection, you can probably just pass them as a strongly typed POCO into your static extension, which will add some clarity as to the required incoming parameters.

```
public class MyAuthenticationOptions
{
   public string Authority { get; set; }
   public string ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

and then use [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/) to bind to an instance:

```
// Replace the quoted section with your config section 
services.AddMyAuthentication(Configuration.GetSection("MyAuthenticationOptions").Get<MyAuthenticationOptions>();
```

And finally update your extension method to accept the object:

```
 public static IServiceCollectionAddMyAuthentication(this IServiceCollection services, MyAuthenticationOptions options); //...
```